# Identify alternating Uppercase and lower case characters in python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am having data as follows,

```
data['word']

1  Word1
2  WoRdqwertf point
3  lengthy word
4  AbCdEasc
5  Not to be filtered
6  GiBeRrIsH
7  zSxDcFvGnnn
```

I want to find out alternating capital and small letters in the string and remove those rows containing words like these. For ex., if we see here, `WoRdqwertf , AbCdEasc, GiBeRrIsH,zSxDcFvGnnn` has alternating characters and I need these to be removed.

The point here is, the first row which contains `Word1` shouldn't be removed because it has only one caps followed by one small. I want to remove the rows only when it has a caps, small, caps arrangement or small, caps, small arrangement. My output here should be,

```
data['word']

1  Word1
3  lengthy word
5  Not to be filtered
```

Can any body help me or give some idea how to approach this problem?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Try`re.search(r'[a-z][A-Z][a-z]|[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]', x)`

Comment: @depperm I am not very sure how to try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string methods. *Verbose ->*

```
l = ['Word1','WoRdqwertf point','lengthy word','AbCdEasc', 'Not to be filtered','GiBeRrIsH', 'zSxDcFvGnnn']

n = []
for section in l:
    new_section = []
    for w in section.split():
        if w == w.title() or w == w.lower():
            new_section.append(w)
    s = ' '.join(new_section)
    if s:
        n.append(s)
    del new_section
print n
```

*One-Liner* ->

```
print filter(len,[' '.join(w for w in s.split()if w[1:].islower())for s in l])
```

**Output:**

```
['Word1', 'point', 'lengthy word', 'Not to be filtered']
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can I ask for deleting that word alone instead of the entire row ? for example, in WoRdqwertf point, make it point alone and in AbCdEasc make it empty.

Comment: Hmm, that requirement was not in your original post, I'll update in a bit.

Comment: Sorry just now thinking about this.

Comment: Perhaps `re.sub(r'\s*\b(?=\w*(?:[a-z][A-Z]+[a-z]|[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z]))\w+', '', section)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have something like this,  0KKoFeunLBVJxVeUXvlGAZsTrKJ3eaFgnfI. This should be removed, But it is not getting removed. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew btw this has alternating characters in the middle. Not in the starting. I want to find alternating characters anywhere and remove it

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For some reason even this is not working for the above scenario

Comment: @mrdomoboto I can use re.sub instead of search here. But it replaces only that characters. I am getting, dqwertf point for WoRdqwertf point, I want to make it point. Can you help me in doing that?

Comment: Completely changed my approach, now using string methods instead.

Comment: @haimen http://ideone.com/PxIFZx

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot !

Comment: @mrdomoboto Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `filter`

```
data=['Word1','WoRdqwertf point','lengthy word','AbCdEasc','Not to be filtered','GiBeRrIsH','zSxDcFvGnnn']
str_list = filter(lambda item: (item[0].isupper() and item[1:].lower()==item[1:]) or item.islower(), data)
print(list(str_list))
#['Word1', 'lengthy word', 'Not to be filtered']
```

Filter will only add items that are lowercase `item.islower()` and items that start with capital only `(item[0].isupper() and item[1:].lower()==item[1:])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `^(?:\w[a-z0-9]*(?: |$))*$`:

```
data = ['Word1','WoRdqwertf point','lengthy word','AbCdEasc', 'Not to be filtered','GiBeRrIsH', 'zSxDcFvGnnn']
import re
for line in data:
    if re.search(r'^(?:\w[a-z0-9]*(?: |$))*$', line):
         print (line)
```

See [live](https://repl.it/Crsr)

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution as well:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'(?=.*(?:\b[A-Z][a-z\d]+\b)|^[a-z ]+$).+')

lst = ['Word1', 'WoRdqwertf point', 'lengthy word', 'AbCdEasc', 'Not to be filtered', 'GiBeRrIsH', 'zSxDcFvGnnn']
new_list = [item \
            for item in lst \
            if rx.match(item)]

print(new_list)
# ['Word1', 'lengthy word', 'Not to be filtered']
```